# AnimatedWidget and AnimatedBuilder in Flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-animation

**Hi everyone** ，I have a problem, I don’t understand the difference between `AnimatedWidget` and `AnimatedBuilder`. The comments in the source code are as follows:

**AnimatedWidget:**

```
/// For more complex case involving additional state, consider using
/// [AnimatedBuilder].
```

**AnimatedBuilder:**

```
/// For simple cases without additional state, consider using
/// [AnimatedWidget].
```

I want to know how to choose between them, because I don't quite understand the documentation, thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There's no real difference between them besides the syntax needed to use it.

To be clear, this is the code of `AnimatedBuilder` :

```
class AnimatedBuilder extends AnimatedWidget {
  const AnimatedBuilder({
    Key key,
    @required Listenable animation,
    @required this.builder,
    this.child,
  }) : assert(builder != null),
      super(key: key, listenable: animation);

  final TransitionBuilder builder;
  final Widget child;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return builder(context, child);
  }
}
```

...Yup, does nothing

From this code we can clearly see that `AnimatedBuilder` is just a different syntax of using `AnimatedWidget`. Since `AnimatedBuilder` is an `AnimatedWidget` that delegate all the layout logic to a callback

So in the end, it's really up to you. Both do the same thing. Use what makes it more readable for you

Comment: This...isn't correct at all.  The AnimatedBuilder always uses the same child instance, which can drastically reduce the amount of building & painting, if the child doesn't depend on animation values.  For example, a translation which moves a  snackbar on screen.

Comment: But you can do exactly that with `AnimatedWidget` too. Nothing prevents you from storing that "child" into a field of your class

Comment: @JonahWilliams All the `XTransition` widgets such as [`AlignTransition`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/AlignTransition-class.html) follow this pattern : AnimatedWidget that takes a child as parameter

Answer (score 2):

Both the **animatedWidget** and **animatedBuilder** do the same work  related to the animations.

> before moving on u must know that to create an animation we must require atleast two things **1.** The **animation  itself** and **2.** The widget on which we are going to apply the animation.

The **clear cut** difference between then is :

- **AnimatedWidget** only takes animation as a parameter whereas **AnimatedBuilder** takes two arguments "child" and "animation".
- **AnimatedWidget** is implemented as a class extending **AnimatedWidget**.
  E.g.

> class abc extends AnimatedWidget

Whereas **AnimatedBuilder** is implemented as a widget inside a class.
E.g.

> child : AnimatedBuilder( .....),

Now, although both do the same work but both have different ways of doing it. In AnimatedWidget it has its own child so we have to pass only the animation.whereas in **AnimatedBuilder** we need to pass both child and animation.

Take **AnimatedWidget** for example u can use the same AnimatedWidget class for any number of animations with different values.

Now you will be thinking that if **AnimatedWidget** can do the thing why we need **AnimatedBuilder**?

The answer is simple

> Changing the animation in **AnimatedWidget** requires changing the widget that renders the logo or our child. So what **AnimatedBuilder** did is to provided a choice to is to pass both child of your choice and animation explicitly.