# Differences between AnimatedBuilder and StatefulWidget in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, animation, statefulwidget

From my point of view, all animations continuously render the widget with some often-changed value. For example, a spinning hand on a clock has a value called 'angle' to indicate its position.

In Flutter, it seems that [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html) is enough for it. My question is:

- What functions do [`AnimatedBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html)/[`AnimatedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html) have?
- What are the differences between [`AnimatedBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedBuilder-class.html)/[`AnimatedWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AnimatedWidget-class.html) and [`StatefulWidget`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/StatefulWidget-class.html)?

Comment: there is a typo (probably): `AnimationBuilder` -> `AnimatedBuilder`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [AnimatedWidget and AnimatedBuilder in Flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51694871/animatedwidget-and-animatedbuilder-in-flutter)

Comment: @AlexRintt Thanks! I have added api links to make it clearer.

Comment: @AlexRintt Not really. What confuses me is the differences between `StatefulWidget` and `AnimatedWidget`. It seems that they both listen to a value (for `StatefulWidget` state, for `AnimatedWidget` listenable), and when the value changes, they rebuild themseleves. So, why not use `StatefulWidget` to create animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<sub>I'll assume that `AnimationBuilder` is `AnimatedBuilder` because there is no such class as `AnimationBuilder` in the Flutter SDK.</sub>

---

### Short answer

There are no differences besides the class names and the parameters.

### Long answer

> In Flutter, it seems that StatefulWidget is enough for it.

You are right.

> What functions do `AnimatedBuilder`/`AnimatedWidget` have?

**Nothing special, they are classes that exists only to wrap common/boilerplate code**, see:

- `AnimatedWidget`: [flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart#L108-L132) is simply a StatefulWidget that takes a listenable and triggers the `setState` whenever the listanable notifies a change.
- The `AnimatedBuilder`: [flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter/lib/src/widgets/transitions.dart#L1145) is a subclass of `ListenableBuilder` which is a subclass of `AnimatedWidget` (!), the only difference is that `AnimatedBuilder` uses your callback as the `build` method of `AnimatedWidget`.

That being said, lets go to the code:

- `AnimatedBuilder` is simply a `StatefulWidget` that uses your callback function (`builder: (...) { }`) as build method. It also triggers `setState` everytime the Listenable (`animation`) notifies a change.

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center( // The [Center] widget instance will not rebuild.
    child: AnimatedBuilder(
      animation: animation,
      builder: (context, child) {
        return /* Widge tree that will rebuild when [animation] changes. */;
      },
    ),
  );
}
```

- The equivalent code using `AnimatedWidget` is:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
  return Center( // The [Center] widget instance will not rebuild.
    child: MyAnimatedWidget(animation: animation),
  );
}

// ...

class MyAnimatedWidget extends AnimatedWidget {
  const MyAnimatedWidget({required Listenable animation}) : super(listenable: animation);

  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return /* Widge tree that will rebuild when [animation] changes. */;
  }
}
```

> What are the differences between AnimatedBuilder/AnimatedWidget and StatefulWidget?

As I said, there is no semantic or real difference. `AnimatedWidget` and `AnimatedBuilder` are only **abstractions** of `StatefulWidget`.

Comment: Thanks for diving into source codes! It solves my question perfectly!